# Laravel use $fillable in model more times to add records multiple times

Tags: php, laravel

I have one table with structure give below image.

I am adding menu first with MenuController:

```
public function storeData(Request $request)
{
    $menu = new Menu($request->all());
    $menu->save();
}
```

and after that I add sub menu of the menu added with:

```
public function storeSubMenu(Request $request)
{
    $menu = new Menu($request->all());
    $menu->save();
}
```

And into Menu model file I used:

```
protected $fillable = ['mane', 'slug','sub_menu', 'sub_menu_slug','parent_menu_id'];
```

So When I am filling menu and submenu form I don't want to pass the data which is not necessary like 1. for the menu not need to pass sub_menu items, 2. for sub menu not need to pass menu name and slug also.

I use $fillable two times and get error of adding data to database. So how use $request->all() for both method to store data? Any help for me to do this?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

unless you cook your own query for this, why don't you make two model ? one for Menu and other one for submenu with one-to-one relationship with menu items? 
if you consider this then i will add some code here or i will have to think in other way.

Comment: You don't need two models, you can have a one to many relationship to the same model.

Comment: Raihan, If I use two models for this it's ok but I have only one table so it's possible to call one table into two models?
If this happens with two models add your code.

Comment: @Devon how to create one to many relationship with same model and add data to database?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, why wouldn't it be?  You can create unlimited classes using the same table, just set the `$table` property.

Comment: @kuldeepsankdecha Just set the related model to the same model when creating the relationship method.

Answer (score 0):

When use `$fillable`, you can pass more params, but only in `$fillable` will be added. See the way of writing it. Check [Eloquent Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) for detail.

```
$menu = Menu::create($request->all());
```